# Which permutation am I? Or: what is a bijection $f:S_n \rightarrow \{1,2,\ldots,n!\}$ such that we can compute $f(\beta)$ easily?

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and assume that $S_n$ is ordered in some way, i.e., $$S_n=\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_{n!}\}.$$  We are able to choose this ordering on $S_n$, and should do so to make the problem easier.

**Question**: Suppose we have a permutation $\beta \in S_n$ and want to compute $i$ such that $\beta=\alpha_i$.  How can we do this efficiently?

Essentially, I want a bijection $f:S_n \rightarrow \{1,2,\ldots,n!\}$ such that I can compute $f(\beta)$ easily.

This is for a potential cryptographic application, but it's in the "brainstorm" stage at the moment, so I won't bother describing it.  This is a proof-of-concept for that application (i.e. if this doesn't work, it's likely that what I have in mind won't work either).  If it makes any difference, $n$ will be fixed and around $10$ to $20$.

Comment: By curiosity, why do you need a bijection ? A hashing function won't be enough?

Comment: The permutation is going to index a "starting point" in a stream cipher.  We must have that two random permutations are unlikely to give the starting point.  And ideally, all possible starting points are achievable in some way.  It's possible that a hashing function would be enough practically, though (especially if we increase $n$), although I hadn't thought about it until you mentioned it.

Comment: This is covered in Knuth's _Art of Computer Programming_, in volume 4 (enumerating permutations).  One easy way is to 'unroll' the permutation: for each index $i$ from $n$ down to $1$, take note of where $i$ is in your permutation and then swap it into its 'correct' position (i.e., position $i$). It's easy to see that this operation is one-to-one with the set of vectors $\langle v_n, v_{n-1},\ldots, v_1\rangle$ where $1\leq v_i\leq i$ for each $i$; this can then easily be put into 1-1 correspondence with the numbers $1\ldots n!$ via the usual mixed-radix methods.

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of lexicographic ordering:
I will illustrate this for n=4 (partially!)
That is first list all permutations starting with 1. There are 6 of them, and so those with  2 at 2nd position come first, and then those with 3 at 2nd position:
We use recursion to list them,
[1,2,3,4], [1,2,4,3], [1,3,2,4],[1,3,4,2]

Now the 6 permutations with 2 at first:
[2,1,3,4], [2,1,4,3], [2,3,1,4], [2,3,4,1]

and so on.